# List row if conditions are met

Tags: google-sheets

I have a master membership database where one of the columns are the end date of the membership.

Is it possible to list all rows from the master sheet on another sheet - but without the rows containing expired memberships.

This is so I can have a single sheet with only current members.

If this is possible, I would also like to have one sheet for memberships who are canceled, but still active, and one sheet with memberships that are expired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible with help of two different formulas:

`=filter(master!a:k, c:c = "")`

Where column c is your dates. Or this formula:

```
=query(master!a:k, "select * where C is null")
```